# Autoload classes in MODX

Tags: php, modx, modx-revolution

Does soembody have better solution to load custom classes in MODx

First create folder classes inside create  some class

**phpmailer.php**

Make PLUGIN some Autoloader call on event, i still do not know all events maybe i have made a mistake,

**OnLoadWebDocument**

**PLUGIN**

```
<?php
//PATHS
define("_CLASSES",_APP_PATH."classes/");

function __autoload($classname){
    require_once(_CLASSES.$classname.".php");
}
?>
```

And then is snippets use like

**SNIPPET**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
```

Will it work,  have you use it that way, because than we can make a lot of our classes to use and not to write all class in snippet? 
or maybe use

```
$modx->loadClass();
```

Comment: txanks on your 'great' answer

Comment: [answer vs. comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette)

Comment: Again you are the greatest :)

Comment: `:D` LoL. Sorry buddy. `:)`